# How to rotate images at different angles randomly in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-rotation, data-augmentation

I know that I can rotate images in tensorflow using `tf.contrib.image.rotate`. But suppose I want to apply the rotation randomly at an angle between -0.3 and 0.3 in radians as follows:

```
images = tf.contrib.image.rotate(images, tf.random_uniform(shape=[batch_size], minval=-0.3, maxval=0.3, seed=mseed), interpolation='BILINEAR')
```

So far this will work fine. But the problem arises when the batch size changes on the last iteration and I got an error. So how to fix this code and make it work in all case scenarios? Please note that the inputs images are fed using `tf.data.Dataset` api.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 8):

You can't feed `tf.contrib.image.rotate` with an angles tensor.

But if you inspect the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/contrib/image/python/ops/image_ops.py) you can see it just makes a bunch of argument validations, and then:

```
image_height = math_ops.cast(array_ops.shape(images)[1],
                             dtypes.float32)[None]
image_width = math_ops.cast(array_ops.shape(images)[2],
                            dtypes.float32)[None]
output = transform(
    images,
    angles_to_projective_transforms(angles, image_height, image_width),
                                    interpolation=interpolation)
```

`tf.contrib.image.transform()` receives a projective transform matrix.
`tf.contrib.image.angles_to_projective_transforms()` generates projective transforms from the rotation angles.

Both accept tensors as arguments, so you can just call the underlying functions.

---

Here is an example using MNIST

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load mnist
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist
import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot = True)

# Tensorflow random angle rotation
input_size = mnist.train.images.shape[1]
side_size = int(np.sqrt(input_size))

dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_size])
images = tf.reshape(dataset, (-1, side_size, side_size, 1))
random_angles = tf.random.uniform(shape = (tf.shape(images)[0], ), minval = -np
    .pi / 4, maxval = np.pi / 4)

rotated_images = tf.contrib.image.transform(
    images,
    tf.contrib.image.angles_to_projective_transforms(
        random_angles, tf.cast(tf.shape(images)[1], tf.float32), tf.cast(tf
            .shape(images)[2], tf.float32)
    ))

# Run and Print
sess = tf.Session()
result = sess.run(rotated_images, feed_dict = {
    dataset: mnist.train.images,
})

original = np.reshape(mnist.train.images * 255, (-1, side_size, side_size)).astype(
    np.uint8)
rotated = np.reshape(result * 255, (-1, side_size, side_size)).astype(np.uint8)


# Print 10 random samples
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 10, figsize = (15, 4.5))
choice = np.random.choice(range(len(mnist.test.labels)), 10)
for k in range(10):
    axes[0][k].set_axis_off()
axes[0][k].imshow(original[choice[k, ]], interpolation = 'nearest', \
    cmap = 'gray')
axes[1][k].set_axis_off()
axes[1][k].imshow(rotated[choice[k, ]], interpolation = 'nearest', \
    cmap = 'gray')
```

[image]